# Can I create table as select using WITH clausule

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I would like to create table using WITH clause - e.g to do sth like this:

```
With t1 as ( select a, b, c from x1 )
, t2 as ( select p, q, r from x2 )

create table T as 
select a,b,c,q,r 
from t1 join t2 on t1.a = t2.p
;
```

But when I execute this, I got the `ORA-00928`

Of course my query is more complicated but when I execute it without create table, it works... .. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why not? You just have to follow the syntax, i.e. `CREATE TABLE` first, `WITH` factoring clause next.

```
SQL> create table t as
  2    with test as (select empno, ename, job, sal from emp)
  3    select * from test;

Table created.

SQL> select * From t;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK            920
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        1600
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        1250
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         2975
<snip>
```